# локальный компьютер и linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток товарищи. Возникла проблема, есть локальный системный блок который используется как некий сервер(для каких целей не интересовался). Попросили переустановить linux, так как до этого поставили криво. Суть вопроса: как переустановить linux через программу PuTTY? Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, вы хотите переустановить операционную систему типа Linux (какую конкретно вы не указали), удаленно, через ssh клиент для Windows?

Comment: извиняюсь, если правильно понимаю я не написал эти значения ОС
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: и все же вы действительно хотите удаленно установить Ubuntu с помощью ssh-клиента с компьютера под управлением Windows? Вы хотите установить ОС удаленно на персональный компьютер ваших знакомых (условно) или речь идет о сервере у хостинг-провайдера?

Comment: во первых, непонятно зачем ставить `Ubuntu 18` срок поддержки которой истекает через пару месяцев. 

Во вторых, `... переустановить linux, так как до этого поставили криво.` - я так понимаю криво но он всё же работает что позволяет подключатся к нему по ssh ? тогда почему просто не исправить эту кривость ?

В третьих, какой в действительности доступ имеются к `локальному системному блоку` ? тока ssh доступ к `кривой` системе или всё же есть возможность чтобы кто-то вставил загрузочную флешку  с той же [ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) после чего подключится к ней по ssh ?

Comment: "и все же вы действительно хотите удаленно установить Ubuntu с помощью ssh-клиента с компьютера под управлением Windows? Вы хотите установить ОС удаленно на персональный компьютер ваших знакомых (условно)" - да. это все обговорено. просто я маленький пенек в этом деле, как собственно как и тот кто попросил, так сказать обучения ради. переустановить нужно потому что некоторые программы работают не корректно

Comment: "чтобы кто-то вставил загрузочную флешку с той же ubuntu server после чего подключится к ней по ssh ?" - правильно ли я понимаю, что эта реализация проще будет. т.е. установка ОС и из под биоса только удаленно?